# how to convert string to numpy array?like [(160, 179), (243, 179), (203, 227), (166, 269), (236, 269)]

Tags: python

I hava a string ,like "[(160, 179), (243, 179), (203, 227), (166, 269), (236, 269)]".I want to know how to convert it to a 5by2numpy array using python?

I have tried this way

np.asarray(xxx)

but get somthing wrong

thx!

Comment: Where are you getting such a string? That string represents a valid Python literal, so you could use `eval` or the safer `ast.literal_eval`. However, you probably should fix whatever upstream process is generating such a string. Likely, this is the result of a bad decision regarding serialization.

Comment: Your asking the wrong question, your question should be "How to convert a list in string to a list"

Comment: i hava done this by using this code:        label=np.asarray(re.findall('(\d+)',raw_lmk),dtype=np.float32).reshape(-1,2)

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way, but you can always try eval

```
 >>> import ast
 >>> lst = ast.literal_eval('["A","B" ,"C" ," D"]')
 >>> lst
["A", "B", "C", " D"]
```

then you can convert it to an np array like you would do with any python list.

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>lst = numpy.array(lst)
```

Hope that helped.